# search and print specific date in a log file

Tags: shell, date, logfile

I'm working with a log file and I want to print from a specific day till the end of it . that specific date is ($sd=27/Dec/2002) for example. now I want to search for this day and print from it till the end of log file ! but what if 27/Dec is not among items in log file ? it should search for items >= $sd (27/Dec) , how could I do this?

this code just search for $Sd which is 27/Dec/2002 , I want to search for items >= $sd

```
sed -n "$(awk '/'$sd'/ {print NR}' serverlog.log.log | head -1),$ p" serveerlog.log|cut -d: -f1
```

example of log file :

```
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.132.36.66 - - [28/Dec/2002:19:33:29 +0100]
```

and the log file is sorted !

Comment: show some example of your log file. and are your log entries already sorted right? later entries were always appended to the file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it would be very easy with awk. see the example below:

```
kent$  cat log.txt
213.64.237.213 - - [20/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [20/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [20/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [20/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [20/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.132.36.66 - - [28/Dec/2002:19:33:29 +0100]

kent$  sd=21/Dec/2002




kent$  awk -F'[:[]' -v d=$sd '$2>d' log.txt
```

**output**

```
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [23/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.64.237.213 - - [25/Dec/2002:03:02:22 +0100]
213.132.36.66 - - [28/Dec/2002:19:33:29 +0100]
```

**update**

try this awk line: $sd is the variable. hope that it would work for you.

```
kent$  awk -F'[:[]' -v vd=$sd 'BEGIN{ gsub(/\//," ",vd);"date +%s -d \""vd"\""|getline d} {p=$0;  gsub(/\//," ",$2); "date +%s -d \""$2"\""|getline o;if(o>d) print p}' log.txt
```

Comment: I tested it ! it has problem and print the whole logfile or sth non relevant :((((

Comment: based on the example data(log and variable), the codes above worked.

Comment: but on the original log file which is contained more than 14000 items , it prints something non-relevant !

Comment: @matarsak, could you please try the example data in my answer? see if it works there.  if the date format in your variable and in file are same?  can you paste one entire line of your log entry?

Comment: yeah I checked with your input , the result is the same ! but with original log file noooo . it does not works                           213.46.27.204 - - [01/Jan/2003:12:55:21 +0100] "GET /scripts/..%252f../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0" 404 - "" ""

Comment: there must be some different between the example you gave and the real file then..

Comment: no they are the same ! the original log file is like this              [01/Jan/2003:12:55:21 +0100] "GET /scripts/..%252f../winnt/system32/cmd.exe?/c+dir HTTP/1.0" 404 - "" ""

Comment: could I use this for time as well ? I mean how could I print from a specific time exactly like this !